# Round up when multiplying an integer by 0.5

Tags: java

Is there a way to automatically round up a value in java?

For example:

```
//generate a random integer value
int randomVal = RandomHelper.nextIntFromTo(1, otherVal);

/* then divide the integer value in half... the error I am getting is that its a double, probably 
because the number generated isn't an even number, but I NEED it to be an integer. Can I round up?*/
int value = randomVal * 0.5;
```

Comment: Uhm, [Math.ceil](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double))?

Comment: To round up, you just do Math.ceil(x)

Comment: Why is somebody voting to reopen this when there's a clear duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.ceil()`:

```
int value = (int)Math.ceil(randomVal * 0.5);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add 1 then divide by 2 instead of multiplying by 0.5. That way, you avoid a floating point operation followed by a conversion to int.

```
int value = (randomVal + 1) / 2;
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but there is no difference between dividing by 2 and multiplying by 0.5

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: There is; with one you can effectively use `Math.ceil`, with the other, you can't.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The difference is in the resulting type. Multiplying by 0.5 results in a double that requires casting.

Comment: However, this doesn't actually solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I overlooked the requirement to round up. This is now taken care of.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You may notice that the question is about integer division not necessarily floating point division. This does not make it a duplicate question.